# how to display multiple pngs in a grid using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of file names, located in the same folder as the jupyter notebook.

fnames = `['foo.png', 'my_img.png', 'img1.png', ..... 'last_img.png']`

I'd like to display these images in a grid inside a notebook output cell, specifying:

- number of rows
- number of columns
- image dims, in pixels, to display (same dims for each image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A deeper dive, you can view in `Tabs` using `ipywidgets` as an alternative**:

```
import os
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

# Define a useful function
def get_image(f_path):
    '''
    Returns the image from a path
    '''
    img_labs = ['jpg','png']
    if any(x in img_labs for x in f_path.split('.')):
        file = os.path.join(folder,f_path)
        image = open(file,'rb').read()
        return image

# Do the actual work here
folder = 'Some Path to a Folder of Images'
files  = os.listdir(folder)
images = [get_image(x) for x in files]
children = [widgets.Image(value = img) for img in images if str(type(img)) != '<class \'NoneType\'>']
labels = ['{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(children))]

# Customize your layout here:
box_layout = widgets.Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    align_items='stretch',
    border='solid',
    width='50%')

# Create the widget
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children

# Label em'!
for i in range(len(children)):
    tab.set_title(i,labels[i])

display(tab)
```

For more extensive details, visit the [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-Grid-layout).

Comment: wow.  This worked great and is a better solution than the grid I was looking for.  I will modify this so that each tab is labelled w the name of the image.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

directory = "./Images/"
images = os.listdir(directory)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
columns = 2
rows = np.ceil(len(images))

for x, i in enumerate(images):
    path =  os.path.join("./Images/",i)
    img = plt.imread(path)
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, x+1)
    plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: this parses 4 of the images, but then throws an error: `ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 4, not 5` .      full error here: https://imgur.com/a/PlPZQTr

Comment: Yeah, you need to set the number of rows and columns accordingly, if you have 10 images set you rows to 5 and columns to 2 to accommodate all 10 images.

Comment: thanks, I upvoted you for the help, but going to leave Yaakov Bressler answer as accepted.

Comment: Hahaha...no problem @3z33etm, at the end of the day we are helping each other to learn..